# How do I stop Excel from formatting numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a csv file exported from a Password manager that I want to clean up. It is full of a variety of numbers: IP addresses, passwords, dates, epoch time, credit card numbers, zip codes, phone numbers, HEX nubmers, etc. When I import it into Excel, many of the numbers are converted to dates, scientific notation, decimals, etc. **The columns do not always line up**, so I can't select one column and format it a specific way. What I want is Excel to NOT FORMAT THE NUMBERS so I can tell if they are credit card numbers, phone numbers, dates, etc.

Comment: Just tell Excel's Import Text Wizard that all fields are ***Text***

Answer (score 3):

Tell the Text Import Wizard that all fields are ***Text***:

[image]

Comment: In many cases when a file is CSV the wizard is never displayed so that you can specify how to import fields. If you change the file extension to txt, you will at least have that option available

Comment: This doesn't always work. I have a text value "11081479191112100000" which happens to be all digits (in most other rows, there are some letters in the value) and even as Text, it displays as "1.10815E+19".